# RcppArmadillo eig_sym compilation issue

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo

I am trying to get the eigenvalues with Rcpparmadillo as in this example: [http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/armadillo-eigenvalues]

When I made it through the cppFunction it’s work fine. However, when I made a .cpp file and try to incorporate it in my package I have the following error during the compilation process:

> C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/RcppArmadillo/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp:474:96: note: #pragma message: WARNING: use of OpenMP disabled; this compiler doesn't support OpenMP 3.0+
>      #pragma message ("WARNING: use of OpenMP disabled; this compiler doesn't support OpenMP 3.0+")
>                                                                                                   ^
>   C:/RBuildTools/3.4/mingw_64/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o test.dll tmp.def RcppExports.o binarize_matrix.o char_uniqueC.o colSumsBinaryC.o colSumsC.o df_to_gbi1.o df_to_gbi_focal.o dimC.o edgelist_to_matrix.o ei.o empty_gbi.o equal_0.o extract_charcterVector_elements.o extract_col.o extract_numericVector_elements.o extract_row.o extract_value_from_id.o filtering_matrix.o find_col.o find_matrix_zero.o find_row.o get_association_matrix.o intersectC.o is_squareC.o lapplyC.o levelsC.o matchC.o perm_for_data_stream1C.o perm_for_data_stream_Control_factor.o randomization_vetor.o rcpp_hello.o rcpp_hello_world.o reachC.o reachC2.o rowSumsBinaryC.o rowSumsC.o strengthC.o strengthSymC.o sumC.o sup_0.o unmatchC.o vector_multiplication.o -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib/x64 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/x64 -lR
>   ei.o:ei.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma6auxlib7eig_symIdNS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS_3ColIT_EERKNS_4BaseIS5_T0_EE[_ZN4arma6auxlib7eig_symIdNS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS_3ColIT_EERKNS_4BaseIS5_T0_EE]+0x5fa): undefined reference to `dsyev_'
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   no DLL was created

**Edit 1**
I am using the same code as the one on the url:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec ei(arma::mat M) {
return arma::eig_sym(M);
}
```

I am on windows 10, Rstudio and R-3.4.1, RcppArmadillo 0.7.960.1.2, Rcpp 0.12.12

**Edit2**

Sorry. The error appear only when I add this function. This seem to be the error:

ei.o:ei.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma6auxlib7eig_symIdNS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS_3ColIT_EERKNS_4BaseIS5_T0_EE[_ZN4arma6auxlib7eig_symIdNS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS_3ColIT_EERKNS_4BaseIS5_T0_EE]+0x5fa): undefined reference to `dsyev_'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'test'

It seems to be related to the compiler, as before that I have this:

C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/RcppArmadillo/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp:474:96: note: #pragma message: WARNING: use of OpenMP disabled; this compiler doesn't support OpenMP 3.0+
   #pragma message ("WARNING: use of OpenMP disabled; this compiler doesn't support OpenMP 3.0+")

Could someone help me please?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Not reproducible, incomplete, poorly formatted, Make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Hi  Dirk Eddelbuettel, I updated my post, I am ready to give extra detail if require.

Comment: Come on now---the error message lists dozen of files, yet you talk about notbeing able to replicate the Gallery post.  These are *not the same thing* so don't pretend they are.  And your error message is still unreadable.  Don't use markdown quote on it.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to misunderstand something. When R source such a file via Rcpp, it links to *the LAPACK / BLAS libraries it uses* so that error can only arise if you (wrongly) assume to build a `main()` program or something.

Here is a shorter but fully equivalent version of the code, shown as compiled, linked, loaded and executed in four lines of an R session:

```
> library(Rcpp)     # load Rcpp just in case
> cppFunction("arma::vec ei(arma::mat M) { return arma::eig_sym(M); }", 
+              depends="RcppArmadillo")      # linebreak for exposition
> ei(matrix(c(2.0, 0, 0, 1.0), 2, 2))
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
>
```

Please try those four lines, and only those four lines. Methinks you have a different problem.

Comment: Of course it does. But does that mean you can just copy this into your own code and completely ignore build instructions?  No, it does not.

Comment: I have the following error: Error in .Primitive(".Call")(<pointer: (nil)>, M) : 
  NULL value passed as symbol address

Comment: You still refuse to show your code, and your build instructions.  You continue to point to known working code, and saying it does not work for you _without giving us the ability to help you_.  This will go nowhere.

Comment: Dear Dirk Eddelbuettel, I am sorry, I am not familiar with compilation errors if they are not related to coding error in the function. I will check by my own and come back when I acquire enough knowledge about compilation processes. I would like to thank you and I am sorry to make you lose your time.

Comment: See [this on how to form an effective post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on StackOverflow.